# Bad things combining to make something good

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word (or two words) that means something along the lines, "Two bad things coming together to make something good." When I say things it could mean events or objects or people or anything, that part is quite flexible. But it has to be a combination of *two*.

Alternatively I wouldn't mind a word that would mean something like, "two bad things combining to make something far far worse" either.
Thanks!

EDIT: It needs to be obvious that two *bad* things are combining. Also I can't use a phrase. I'm hoping to convert the word/2 words into a name, so that should help understand what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Heard this in a movie once, it's not Shakespeare, but I thought it was catchy :)

> Two wrongs make a right... an outright catastrophe.

Comment: I'm looking for a word, or maybe even two. The phrase sounds nice but is a little longer than what I was looking for.

Comment: maybe if you post the actual sentence (minus the word), we or someone else can think of a good word for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Actions combining to produce some unforeseen good result could be said to be **[fortuitous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortuitous)** -

> … the intensification of competition on the job market has only exacerbated our class anxiety, as hiring seems all the more uncertain if not *fortuitous*. —Jeffrey J. Williams, *College English*, November 2003

This is not restricted to combinations of pairs-of-things (OP's qualification), but can work for single or multiple events combining.

Comment: Sorry for not including this information in the original post, but it needs to be evident that two *bad* things are coming together. Since "fortuitous" doesn't imply that, it's not really what I was looking for. Once again, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

For your first request,

**The two negatives canceled [each other] out**

I'm sorry it's longer than you wanted, that's the shortest I could think of.

For your second request, you could make a two-word phrase, with the second word being *compounded*.  For example,

**Evil compounded** OR **Villainy compounded**

Answer (score -2):

For two or more bad things that combine or interact to produce something better, I suggest:

*antifragile*

> Anti-fragility is the opposite of fragility, describing things that not only gain from combining stress but may need it to survive and flourish.

For two or more bad things that combine or interact to produce something worse, I suggest:

*clusterfuck*

> a complete failure or very serious problem in which many mistakes or problems happen at the same time